# UIButton with a single rounded corner

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I would like to know how can I create something that looks like what the Twitter guys put in their UITableView.

The screenshot is the following:
[image]

What I am referring to are the four-cells-in-one that looks so good to summarise things up.
Do you have any clue? I though about [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) but I can't achieve that.

My idea is to create 4 png files and then apply those images to 4 buttons and drop them in a cell. I can't use Photoshop, really. I'm so denied.

Thank you for any suggestions/hunches you can give to me

Comment: Just from an quick glance, I would guess the twitter app subclassed a UITableViewCell. You can customize subviews with the contentView property.

Comment: Yes, I was asking for a way to build my own cell that would look just like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out TTTQuadrantcontrol on github 
https://github.com/mattt/TTTQuadrantControl

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is indeed to use PNG images and a UIButton with a buttonType of `UIButtonTypeCustom`. Have a look at [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/), a cheaper and simpler alternative to Photoshop with great support for iOS - I couldn't live without it!